# Place a platform specific button in user interface using react-native

Tags: css, react-native

I have to place a button which shown only in iOS not on android. I have used this style but its not working.

```
...Platform.select({
  android: {
    display:'none',

  },
```

My button is:

```
<Button
      icon
      light
      transparent
      dark
      style={styles.btnIcon}
      disabled={!this.state.canGoBack}
      onPress={this.onBack.bind(this)}
    >
      <Icon name="arrow-back" />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
 render(){
    return (
           <View>
              {Platform.OS == "ios" && 
              <Button onPress= {this.onPressHandler}> 
              {this.state.buttonText}
              </Button>
             }
           </View>
       )}
```

It will add button component for only iOS platform.

Answer (score 0):

There is no styling called `display: "none"` in react-native. So, you have to check the platform and decide if you want to render or not. You can do it like this:

```
<View> 
 {Platform.OS == "ios" && 
   <Button onPress= {this.onPressHandler}> 
     {this.state.buttonText} 
   </Button> 
 } 
</View>
```